# Member variables changes aren't realized across their class

Tags: c++

So whenever my functions call the mouse event (which I've made sure is called) and the vector `StringArray` is updated to have 1 or more strings the else portion of my if-else statement doesn't activate. Isn't the MyFrame class a loop? I'm pretty sure I've had it pick up on changes before so I don't know how to handle this situation specifically.

Note: I've left out other (what I think are irrelevant) components from the code like the MyApp class and other classes/functions found in the boiler plate hello world wxwidgets sample that my project is based around.

I've tried reinitiating the variable again in the bottom, making the vector a wxArray instead, apart from that I'm sat here with no idea on what to do.

```
class MyFrame : public wxFrame{
    public:
        MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size);
                
    private:
        std::vector<std::string> StringArray; 
        void Func(wxMouseEvent& event);

MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size) : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, pos, size) { 

Func();
if (StringArray.size() == 0) {

       // This code runs by default when the app starts up
}
else{
      // This bit doesn't run even when the mouse event is set off and the vector is updated to have at least one string inside
}

void MyFrame::Func(wxMouseEvent& event)
{
         StringArray.push_back("I am a string");  
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what do you expect.  The constructor runs only once in order to create an object. In the beginning the vector is empty and so the `if-branch` is executed. Are you looking for mouse event reaction on when the vector has data? Just execute that piece of code in the handler... otherwise explain what you want the program to do- u current explanation is really vague. And don't do wxArray- the class exist for backward compatibility only and shouldn't be used in a new code.

Comment: @igor im not looking for a mouse event reaction beyond what the above code does, it just adds a string to the vector. Done. The problem is when I go to check the size of the vector in the if-else block and it acts like no string has been added. I want it to pick up on that change

Comment: so are you creating multiple frames in your program? If not - where do you check the vector size? BTW, you code have an error and won't compile...

Comment: @igor this will definitely not compile, like I said I left out the other classes needed to run this bit. I’m not trying to make multiple frames, like I said I’m just trying to have the if statement pick up on the changes in StringArray.size(), which should be of size 1 (with one string inside) after I’ve added that string in the Func function

Comment: StringArray.size() Is what I’m using to pick up on the vector’s size

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through the execution of your code and inspect the relevant variables? It's very helpful to be able to to do that yourself instead of having to ask someone else to essentially do it for you. In this case, you could see whether `fargh` is ever being modified during `MyFrame`'s constructor.

Comment: One more time - constructors execute just once to create an appropriate object of the class. You need to put an else condition to some function other than constructor and call it. Now, I suspect you are doing it but doing it wrong.

Comment: @Igor I'm aware of all of this. I can't call it from the MyFrame class since it's a mouse event that's binded in another member function.

Comment: If you want particular code to execute when a mouse event occurs, why don't you just put it in the function that gets called when the mouse event occurs (`MyFrame::Func`)? On the other hand if you want code in a constructor to be affected by something that happens _after_ the constructor is called, then you're asking for time travel.

Comment: @TheUndeadFish, this is what I'm trying to tell the OP ;-)

Comment: @Pal, you really, really need to post more code. In particular - what does you constructor does, both with if and else. How do you bind the handler. and to what object. Where did you check the size of the array. Better yet - create a minimal reproducible example and post it here. It st not clear from your explanation what are yo trying to achieve.

Comment: There will be a separate `StringArray` in each instance of your `MyFrame` object. Either you are creating new `MyFrame` objects all the time, which have an empty `StringArray` in the beginning, or your mouse event calls another function. It should not call your constructor repeatedly. A constructor is and can be called only once at the beginning of the lifetime of the `MyFrame` object.